# PHP Code in Widget Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed this code in functions.php

```
function php_execute($html){
if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){ ob_start(); eval("?".">".$html);
$html=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
}
return $html;
}
add_filter('widget_text','php_execute',100);
```

I have this logic code in the Widget area.

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
Website designed and developed by <a href="https://www.akvitek.com.au/">Akvitek</a>
<?php } else { ?>
Website designed and developed by Akvitek.
<?php } ?>
```

I am trying to use this widget in footer.

The output shows both the text appearing side by side on all pages.

What is it that I am doing wrong here!

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

just install plugin for that which allow u to add php code in widget

https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/

Comment: I did install that plugin and used the same code in the widget above. but I get the same result.

Comment: check your error log if any error show in .log file

Comment: also just change your theme and test as your theme have some code to conflict with plugin.

Answer (score 0):

PHP execution is inherently dangerous. I'd suggest that a better (safer) way to do it would be using something like [Widget Options](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-options/) to specify where widgets should be visible and setup two separate widgets (one with link and one without).